# Cron job not running on specified time

Tags: cron

I've a cron job that *should* run every day at 1700 hours from Saturday to Sunday. However, it runs on the system at 0100 hours instead.

The schedule descriptor string used to define the table for this particular job in question is: `0 17 * * 0-6`

The system on which this crontab exists is CentOS 5.2 with ISC Cron V4.1 running on it. I did, recently, change the timezone on the system from PDT to BST by creating a symbolic link at `/etc/localtime` pointing to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/GB`. However, I do not believe that to have caused this problem as I remember the cron job running at 0100 hours before.

Any insights? I'd appreciate any help I could get on this. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/214234/crontab-not-running-at-specific-time-but-runs-every-min/1006318#1006318

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crond is likely still in the old timezone, restart it (from a shell with the right timezone) to pick up the new `TZ` variable.

Comment: "However, I do not believe that to have caused this problem as I remember the cron job running at 0100 hours before".  Right, because it was running it at 1700PDT.  And it probably still is.

Comment: You really should not change timezones on a running system without rebooting the system.