# crontab not running at specific time, but runs every min

Tags: debian, cron

I want to run a cron job every day at 8:10pm.

```
10 20 * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.example.com/blah.php
```

However, it doesn't work.

If I try to run it every minutes:

```
* * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.example.com/blah.php
```

It works fine. What gives?

The command "date" yields the correct time on my server.

Comment: Have you checked your log file? cron usually writes to /var/log/messages

Comment: There is nothing regarding the cron job in messages.log

Comment: I found cron entries in syslog and realized the timestamp is off by 5 hours. I thought cron jobs went by the server time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change UTC from yes to no in /etc/default/rcS. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

The above should be working just fine. Here's a list you can try:

- Try a different time - e.g. set it to run 5 minutes after now and see if it works
- Try a different user

  - Or a different crontab (`/etc/crontab` or another user's crontab)
- Try a simpler command (e.g. `echo works > /tmp/cron-works`)

  - You can also just prepend the above to your curl (e.g. `echo works > /tmp/curl-works; curl ...`) or something along these lines
  - It's also good to add another cron entry at the same time which does echo and leave your curl in there as is
- Check the logs - `/var/log/syslog` should show it executing the commands and possible failures
- Confirm your curl actually ran - how do you know whether it ran? I assume you are looking at the logs for `www.example.com` - if so, double-check the logs
- Try special values such as `@houry` (see `man 5 crontab` for the complete list)

Also, how are you authenticating - if it's a network authentication, you may need to confirm this is working **before** any crontab executes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found out the date in my syslog is different than the date I get when I run "date". What gives?

Comment: @Bastien I see you found a solution yourself - tricky one, I might say...

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me with the same situation.
Restarting the cron service helped my server's cron service recognize the changes I made to the system's date.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626135/crontab-linux-not-running-at-specific-time

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
sudo service cron restart or sudo service crond restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the cron service.

```
$ sudo service cron restart
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this will solve the problem described?